# How do I check for logged in user id and return that row first in a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

The query below selects the 'loves' on an item. (think of it as similar to facebooks 'like' system.

There are two tables in use in this select.  A link table (containing itemid, userid, lovetime) and this is joined to a users table in order to retrieve the username/user profile url etc.

```
$lovequery = "select love.lovetime, love.userid as ID, love_users.display_name, love_users.user_url
                    from ".$wpdb->prefix."comment_loves love
                    left join ".$wpdb->prefix."users love_users on love_users.ID=love.userid
                    where commentid = $itemid                   
                    order by love.lovetime desc
                    limit 4

             ";
```

The results are limited to 4 because I simply do not need any more data.  The total count is stored separately in the actual item table to reduce queries.

Once the rows are retrieved from this query I iterate through the array, cross referencing against the total 'lovecount' and build a text string formatted like so:

```
You, John Smith, Joe Bloggs and 4 others love this.
```

This works fine however it fails if the logged in user (YOU) does not have the most recent 'lovetime'

What I want to do is have the currently logged in use always at the top of the returned results even if his/her 'lovetime' is older than the 4 most recent ones so that the string always begins with 'You' if the logged in user has 'loved' this item.

The logged in user id is available in the script as $userid.

To clarify

if I have the following table (the timestamps are written as simple UK dates for legibility purposes):-

```
    userid  commentid  lovetime

    34       3          02/10/2011
    24       3          03/10/2011
    13       3          06/10/2011
    65       3          14/10/2011
    1*       3          10/09/2011

* with userid 1 being the logged in user id
```

I would only get user id's 34,24,13,65 returned in that order due to ordering by 'lovetime'

What I want is for the results to return ideally 1,34,24,65. if that proves too tricky then getting 5 total rows when the userid exists would be okay also.

I hope this is clear enough, it was rather difficult to articulate.

How would I go about modifying the query to ensure the results are as described.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order result by condition like `ORDER BY (ID = "auth_user_id") DESC`

Comment: *sigh* how embarrassing.  Thank you for a quick and perfect answer.  I can't believe I missed that, I am still learning MySQL.  Cheers!!